# How to chain methods in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have the following object.

```
myobj = {
    'item1'{'key1':'value1'},
    'item2'{'key2':'value2'}
}
```

How can I define a function such that I could call:

```
var value = getMyObjItem('item2').getValue();
```

in order to get 'value2'? I would like to avoid defining a 'getItem' (takes item parameter) and 'getItemByValue' (takes two parameters of item and key).

Comment: First of all, your original javascript is invalid. It should have ":" between the items and the {}. Then you can access the objects directly. e.g. `var test = myobj.item2.key2` - http://jsfiddle.net/USD8f/

Comment: So how would that work if item has more than one key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't clear what you wanted, but I did the best I could with the information I had. The following function operates in the exact manner you asked for, and is probably a good example of giving you what you asked for rather than what you needed. Nonetheless:

```
myobj = {
    'item1': {'key1':'value1'},
    'item2': {'key2':'value2'}
};

function getMyObjItem(key) {
    return {
        value: myobj[key]["key" + key.replace("item", "")],
        getValue: function() {
            return this.value;
        }
    };
}

var value = getMyObjItem('item2').getValue(); // will return "value2"
```

Note that this will only work if you maintain the *exact* property scheme that you demonstrated in the example.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit exactly how this works? How is `value` called here? Thanks!